# c++ object created with new keyword does not render; object created on the stack does

Tags: c++, opengl

**Edit**: I have stripped out all texturing and normal mapping but the problem still remains

I am trying to draw a chunk of terrain on the screen. The render function looks like this:

```
void TerrainChunk::Render()
{
   std::cout << "Render Me!\n";
   glColor3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f)
   glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
   for(int x = 1; x < kChunkSize - 1; x++)
   {
      for(int z = 1; z < kChunkSize - 1; z++)
      {
         std::cout << height_map_[x][z] << " ";
         glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
            glVertex3f(x, height_map_[x][z], z);
            glVertex3f(x+1, height_map_[x+1][z], z);       
            glVertex3f(x, height_map_[x][z+1], z+1);
            glVertex3f(x+1, height_map_[x+1][z+1], z+1);
         glEnd();
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;
   }
   glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
}
```

When the object is created on the stack

```
TerrainChunk chunk("chunk1.png", "grass.png");
chunk.Init();
```

it renders perfectly.

When I create it with new

```
TerrainChunk *chunk = new TerrainChunk("chunk1.png", "grass.png");
chunk->Init();
```

nothing shows up. In both cases, Render is being called and the correct heightmap is being printed out. I would expect both of these cases to behave identically.

**Edit**: Here is the Init() code as requested. All it does is load the height map which I've already verified is correct on each call to Render().

```
void TerrainChunk::Init()
{
   std::cout << height_file_ << ", " << texture_file_ << std::endl;

   //Load height map
   SDL_Surface *temp = IMG_Load(height_file_.c_str());
   if(!temp)
   {
      printf("Failed to load chunk.\n");
      exit(-1);
   }
   Uint32 *pixels = (Uint32 *)temp->pixels;
   for(int z = 0; z < kChunkSize; z++)
   {
      for(int x = 0; x < kChunkSize; x++)
      {
         Uint8 r, g, b;
         SDL_GetRGB(pixels[x + z * temp->w], temp->format, &r, &g, &b);
         height_map_[x][z] = g / 12;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't know OpenGL, but are you calling `delete` on `chunk` when you create it in dynamic storage?

Comment: Are you creating those objects at the exact same point in time? I would guess that you might be doing something at which point you don't have a valid context. Put some `glGetError` after chunk->Init() and see if anything shows up.

Comment: What do you do in the destructor of `TerrainChunk`?

Comment: Is it still printing out `"Render me!"` when you allocate on the heap, just not drawing?

Comment: The code in both cases is identical except for switching the construction syntax and the appropriate dots(.) and arrows(->)
It prints out Render Me! and a correct heightmap in both cases

Comment: @Timulus then it should be identical...

Comment: @MuriloVasconcelos Edited typo: I haven't provided a **destructor**

Comment: "destructor" rather than constructor is what @MuriloVasconcelos mentioned

Comment: @Timulus so I have no guess... :(

Comment: @Tim `glGetError()` always comes back clean

Comment: How about posting Init() code as well?

Comment: @DanielLe added. I don't see how that could be the problem but I also don't see how anything could be the problem so...

Comment: functions Init and Render do not placed neither in stack nor in heap. They placed in code segment. But your TerrainChunk's members are placed in stack or in heap. Show the header file, where TerrainChunk class is declared

Comment: I've seen bugs where zero initialization was done in operator new, but those won't run if the instance is on the stack. Also, allocated memory is more likely to have consistent values than stack memory. The unitialized values will often be more chaotic in uninitialized stack space, perhaps a heap allocated instance has a nicer uninitialized value by coincidence. I would put a breakpoint at the end of the constructor and inspect the values of all of the members.

Comment: Also, do you have a debugging tool like OpenGL Profiler (on the Mac)? It can take a snapshot of the OpenGL state and save it as a text file. You can then diff the 2 text files from when it worked and when it didn't and see exactly what's different between them.

Comment: @Timulus Can we see TerrainChunk's constructor?

Comment: This is quite unbelievable. I'd be interested in seeing full code if possible. Are you absolutely sure nothing else is changed? Where is the height_map_ declared? If the output to cout is identical, then for sure glVertex3f() gets called and the same output must be produced. Conclusion: 1) a bug somewhere else in your code, or 2) you did not change just the initialization (be it by mistake or by side-effects).

Comment: Can you make sure that kChunkSize is correctly set via gdb or pint?

Comment: You should try to remove code in your program piece by piece until you have a minimal program exposing the problem, and then post the code here.

Comment: Please post the ctor. It may be that you have different glX- contexts during construction.

Comment: Also, please post the render-loop, or the code triggering the rendering of the terrain.

Answer (score 1):

When the same object works when created on the stack, but doesn't when created in the heap, or vice versa, more often than not it's because a member is left ununitialized. Heap allocations are zero-initialized, and stack allocations aren't. I recommend running your program under valgrind, it will most likely tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with Luchian Grigore: the stack based version will be deleted automatically when you are through using it; the heap based version will only be deleted explicitly.

If you change:

```
TerrainChunk *chunk = new TerrainChunk("chunk1.png", "grass.png");
chunk->Init();
```

To:

```
TerrainChunk *chunk = new TerrainChunk("chunk1.png", "grass.png");
chunk->Init();
delete chunk;
```

Are the results different?